# Mongodb does not use index when value is null

Tags: mongodb, optimization, indexing

I have created index for three attributes - a:1, b:1, c:-1

When searching for:

```
{a: false, b: null, c: {"$lt" : ISODate("2016-06-19T12:19:37.177Z")}}
```

Mongo uses created index, but still needs to fetch "b". So index is used only for a.

But when I search for:

```
{a: false, b: "some value", c: {"$lt" : ISODate("2016-06-19T12:19:37.177Z")}}
```

I does use whole index.

So the question is why Mongo does not use whole index when value is null?

Sparse option does not change anything.

```
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "db.collection",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [ 
            {
                "a" : {
                    "$eq" : false
                }
            }, 
            {
                "b" : {
                    "$eq" : null
                }
            }, 
            {
                "c" : {
                    "$lt" : ISODate("2016-06-19T12:19:37.177Z")
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "COUNT",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "b" : {
                        "$eq" : null
                    }
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "a" : NumberLong(1),
                        "b" : NumberLong(1),
                        "c" : NumberLong(-1)
                    },
                    "indexName" : "a_1_b_1_c_-1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "a" : [ 
                            "[false, false]"
                        ],
                        "b" : [ 
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ],
                        "c" : [ 
                            "(new Date(1466338777177), true)"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : []
},
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 0,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 3,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 578,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 578,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "COUNT",
        "nReturned" : 0,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
        "works" : 579,
        "advanced" : 0,
        "needTime" : 578,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "saveState" : 4,
        "restoreState" : 4,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "nCounted" : 577,
        "nSkipped" : 0,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
            "nReturned" : 577,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 579,
            "advanced" : 577,
            "needTime" : 1,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "saveState" : 4,
            "restoreState" : 4,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "b" : {
                        "$eq" : null
                    }
                },
                "nReturned" : 577,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 579,
                "advanced" : 577,
                "needTime" : 1,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "saveState" : 4,
                "restoreState" : 4,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 578,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 578,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 579,
                    "advanced" : 578,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needFetch" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 4,
                    "restoreState" : 4,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "a" : NumberLong(1),
                        "b" : NumberLong(1),
                        "c" : NumberLong(-1)
                    },
                    "indexName" : "a_1_b_1_c_-1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "c" : [ 
                            "[false, false]"
                        ],
                        "b" : [ 
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ],
                        "c" : [ 
                            "(new Date(1466338777177), true)"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 578,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                    "matchTested" : 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.0.10",
    "gitVersion" : "1e0512f8453d103987f5fbfb87b71e9a131c2a60"
},
"ok" : 1.0
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I have learned that indexing and searching for null works exactly the same way like for other values.

Anyway when doing explain you can notice that for "null" you have extra stage called "FETCH" that can be quite confusing. Despite that number of docs/keys examined is exactly the same (test database contained symmetric data).